# Broadcast receiver is not called everytime

Tags: android

I already tried searching for my answer, but could not get the specific answer I was checking.

Problem:
I am trying to make a call state change receiver. I have registered broadcast receiver in manifest and made a receiver class for it. In its onReceive(), I have registered a PhonsStateListener to listen to Call state changes.
Now when I am receiving a call, onReceive() is called and when disconnected, onReceive is called again properly.
But when I repeated the above process again, onReceive() is called on incoming call , but not upon disconnecting that call.

My manifest for receiver

```
        <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

I have no idea what could be wrong in this. The problem is onReceive() is not called on disconnecting second call. Please let me know if any other code is required. I am checking on Note2 JellyBean 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add this into your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

And don't forget to unregisterReceiver() your Broadcast in your activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(your_broadcast_name);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: I cannot understand the use of wakelock permission here. I am not trying to acquire any wakelock and also , I am not getting any security exception.  Also, I cant understand the reason behind unregister receiver. Also, this is a receiver, so it is also possible that I may not open my activity at all(so onDestroy will not be called) but still receiver should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to obtain permission：

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: yes, it is already there. Hence I am getting it for first time

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your opinion. The problem was with the code of broadcast receiver. I was doing something wrong in the onReceive() method due to which problem was occuring at system level and my process was getting killed. It worked fine after fixing that problem.

Comment: This should be edit in Question  or as comment instead of making it Answer